# Fixing spyder issue

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I've got this issue after I tried to do process of converting .py to .exe, after that I can't even run the spyder and when I launch spyder, this always pop up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Lowe\Anaconda\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\Lowe\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 186, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "C:\Users\Lowe\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 90, in 
from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
File "C:\Users\Lowe\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I guess you used PyInstaller or some other tool to convert your script to an exe file. Those kind of tools install `pyqt5`, which is incompatible with the `pyqt` packages provided by Anaconda. Due to that, I'm afraid you corrupted your installation and you need to reinstall now, sorry

Comment: Thanks, it really works thanks man.